# Package for redirecting from questions to answers

Tags: exsheets, answers, probsoln

Good evening,

could someone tell me which package should I use in order to be redirected from the number of a question to its answer.

In detail, suppose that I have written some questions and their answers in LaTeX numbered.
What should I do , so when I press on the number of the question to be redirected to its respective answer.

*I'm not sure about the tag.*

Comment: `exsheets`, `answers`, `probsoln` .... all of them... and one fine day my own package `arbeitsblatt`, but that's not publish(able) at the moment ;-)

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence In more detail? And then the commands I have to follow?

Comment: No more detail, as each of them works differently. Your question is quite broad, I offered a broad comment

Comment: Ok... let us restrain us down to the answer package... since I have heard of that before , so I guess I could handle that much easier... then what do I do?

Comment: Reading the manual, perhaps? ;-)

Comment: Sounds like a good start!! :)

Comment: A link from the question to the answer, but where exactly? Make the question number a link? Make the whole question title a link? Add some explicit text linking to the answer... depending on your needs `exsheets` may well be able do do this.